# Why do new borns stares at light?

Tags: newborn

I have noticed my new born Baby 3 month old likes staring at light. He also seems to stare at roof , walls and big photographs hanging on wall with expression of astonishment. But he likes to stare at light alot, and seems to use like his eyes got dodged into the light source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baby eyesight develops in stages. In the beginning, everything is very blurry. Lights are often a fixed point that they can see the most clearly and everything surrounding the light is most likely more clear to them.

At month 3, sensitivity to light becomes increased. Perhaps your baby hasn't quite got sensitive to it yet or they have and they are fascinated by it.

Some milestones for baby vision is listed [here](http://www.parents.com/baby/development/physical/understanding-your-babys-developing-vision/)